# Need to find value of element in XML

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Sample XML:

```
<parts>
    <title>computer parts</title>
    <components>
        <hardware>motherboard</hardware>
        <id>1234</id>
    </components>
    <part>
        <item>motherboard</item>
        <manufacturer>asus</manufacturer>
        <model>p3b-f</model>
        <cost> 123.00</cost>
    </part>
    <components>
        <hardware>video card</hardware>
        <id>2345</id>
    </components>
    <part>
        <item>video card</item>
        <manufacturer>ati</manufacturer>
        <model>all-in-wonder pro</model>
        <cost> 160.00</cost>
    </part>
    <components>
        <hardware>sound card</hardware>
        <id>3456</id>
    </components>
    <part>
        <item>sound card</item>
        <manufacturer>creative labs</manufacturer>
        <model>sound blaster live</model>
        <cost> 80.00</cost>
    </part>
</parts>
```

In the above sample XML, I need to first search for the value `motherboard` in the `components` element; if the value is found there, then we need to search the value in the `<part>` element under the `item` tag, if the value is available in the `item` tag, then we should get the value of the `model` tag.

Note: I have highlighted the values that need to be searched and value that needs to be extracted.

How can I do that in Bash?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your code? Have you tried using `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: Don't use bash; Instead use xmllint or xmlstartlet with xpath to get this done. Ideally, you should use a scripting language which has a XML parser.

Comment: can you give an example using the sample xml you have given? I can't understand whether you are looking for a tag named `motherboard` or a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/<hardware>/,/<\/hardware>/ { match($1,/<hardware>.*<\/hardware>/);prod=substr($1,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-21) } /<item>/,/<\/item>/ { match($1,/<item>.*<\/item>/);avail=substr($1,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-13) } /<model>/,/<\/model>/ { match($1,/<model>.*<\/model>/);if (prod=="motherboard" && avail=="motherboard") { print substr($1,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-15) } }' filename
```

I think this is what you are after

```
/<hardware>/,/<\/hardware>/ { 
    match($1,/<hardware>.*<\/hardware>/)
    prod=substr($1,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-21) 
}

/<item>/,/<\/item>/ { 
     match($1,/<item>.*<\/item>/)
     avail=substr($1,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-13) 
}

/<model>/,/<\/model>/ { 
     match($1,/<model>.*<\/model>/)
     if (prod=="motherboard" && avail=="motherboard") { 
           print substr($1,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-15) 
     } 
 }
```

Set search for the hardware tag. Store the entry in a variable prod. Search for the item tag and store the contained element in avail. Search the the model tag and then if prod and avail both equal motherboard, print the element.